# How can one calculate $\int \frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin x+2\cos x}\text{d}x$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Is there any relatively simple (this is from a regular calculus course, so no complex numbers and such) way to calculate the following integral?$$\int \frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin x+2\cos x}\text{d}x$$

I tried to substitute $x=\tan\frac{t}{2}$ and complete the square but that didn't really help:

$$\int\frac{\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}\right)^{2}}{\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}+2\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}}\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\text{d}t=\int \frac{\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}\right)^{2}}{\underbrace{-t^2+t+1}_{\frac{5}{4}-\left ( t-\frac{1}{2} \right )^2}}\text{d}t$$

Comment: Why didn't that help, don't you know how to handle integrals of rational functions?

Comment: It isn't clear (and doesn't appear to be correct) how you got the denominator on the right hand side in then final line.

Comment: Not of the kind $-\frac{4 t^2}{t^6 - t^5 + t^4 - 2 t^3 - t^2 - t - 1}$ @mickep

Comment: You can use a site like [this](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) to show you the steps and answer

Comment: The $1+t^2$ reduced from the one I got from the expression for $dx$ @Chickenmancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way that I think became a bit simpler (in general, the Weierstrass substitution is powerful, but often one can get shorter calculations by not using it).

We know that $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$. Thus, for any $k$, we can write
$$
\sin^2x=(1-k)\sin^2x-k\cos^2x+k.
$$
Let us now choose $k$ so that we get a factorization for the trigonometric part, where one factor is $\sin x+2\cos x$. With the conjugate $\sin x-2\cos x$ we find that 
$$
(\sin x+2\cos x)(\sin x-2\cos x)=\sin^2x-4\cos^2x
$$
so we want to choose $k$ so that $4(1-k)=k$, i.e. $k=4/5$. This means that we write
$$
\sin^2x=\frac{1}{5}(\sin x+2\cos x)(\sin x-2\cos x)+\frac{4}{5}
$$
and our integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{5}\int \bigl(\sin x-2\cos x\bigr)\,dx+\frac{4}{5}\int\frac{1}{\sin x+2\cos x}\,dx.
$$
The first one is easily handled. For the second one, we can proceed in many ways. For example, the substitution
$$
t=\cos x-2\sin x
$$
will give you
$$
-\frac{4}{5}\int\frac{1}{5-t^2}\,dt.
$$
If you prefer, multiplying by $\sin x-2\cos x$, you will get
$$
\frac{4}{5}\int\frac{\sin x-2\cos x}{\sin^2x-4\cos^2x}\,dx
=\frac{4}{5}\int\Bigl(\frac{\sin x}{1-5\cos^2x}-\frac{2\cos x}{5\sin^2x-4}\Bigr)\,dx,
$$
giving two logarithm terms.

Answer (score 1):

i think you denominator is wrong, you will get
$$\frac{-2(t^2-t-1)}{1+t^2}$$ and your integral will be
$$\int \frac{-4t}{(1+t^2)^2(t^2-t-1)}dt$$

Comment: Yeah this is what I wrote down in my notebook (you could recognize it was a typo because of the completing the square formula), somehow here I didn't do it correctly haha... but still

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{\sin x+2\cos x}\times\dfrac{\sin x-2\cos x}{\sin x-2\cos x}=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\sin^2x-4\cos^2x}\sin x-2\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\sin^2x-4\cos^2x}\cos x$$
for the first let $\cos x=u$ and the rest $\sin x=u$.